# Specifying multi css class in stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Good Day.

I have an element that has two three classes assigned to it. Two are assigned in the html, and one is assigned by jQuery as an active class.

Now I want to specify, in CSS, a hover effect but to the one specific element: The "menuItem first" class...

HTML:

```
<ul>     
  <li class="menuItem first"><a href=""><img src="img/sample_slides/1.png" alt="thumbnail" /></a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="img/sample_slides/1.png" alt="thumbnail" /></a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="img/sample_slides/1.png" alt="thumbnail" /></a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="img/sample_slides/1.png" alt="thumbnail" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
li.act,li.act:hover{
    /* The active state of the thumb */
    background:url(img/active_bg2.png) no-repeat;
}

li.act .first, li.act .first:hover{
    /* The active state of the thumb - first class only! */
    background:url(img/active_bg1.png) no-repeat;
}
```

I know the css right above is wrong. What is the right annotation?
Remember that the `.act` class is assigned by jQuery to the active element...

Comment: Extra space in between `.act` and `.first`...

Comment: `li.act,li.act:hover` is equivalent to `li.act`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say

```
li.act .first
```

what you're really saying is "the element with class `first` inside an `<li>` element with class `act`".

If you want to say "the element with both `first` and `act` classes, you'd want to write them out without spaces:

```
li.act.first
```

Following that, to achieve a hover ruleset for said selector, you can just append the pseudo `:hover` as always:

```
li.act.first:hover
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your answer

Answer (score 3):

you have an extra space in your selector

use

```
li.act.first, li.act.first:hover{
    /* The active state of the thumb - first class only! */
    background:url(img/active_bg1.png) no-repeat;
}
```

selector `li.act.first` means the `li` element has both `act` and `first` in the class property.

Answer (score 0):

What you have at the moment is setting the same background colour for both states. So instead you would use,,

```
.first{background-color:#faa;}
.first:hover{background-color:#afa;}
```

Im using background-color here just as a working example,
http://jsfiddle.net/mshtT/

Answer (score 0):

When you write `li class="menuItem first` like the way you did in your first `li` element in HTML, `menuItem` and `first` become two separate classes. To apply the hover effect in just one element you can just use the following CSS

```
.first:hover {
    /*the effect you want*/ (eg. Background: #444;)
}
```

It would only apply to the element that has the `first` class in it, that is your first element.

Comment: thanks, understand your logic, but there are two classes involved, and both needs to be applied when the hover effect happens...The other class is .act, whic is applied by jquery addClass and removeClass